# insert array into database codeigniter

Tags: sql, arrays, codeigniter

i have tried to make sql code in CI, the problem is the `ID_LABEL` at t_publisher is filled with 0 where it should filled with number that taken from t_label..

```
$sql['query1'] = "INSERT into t_user (USER_NAME, USER_PASS, USER_STATUS, USER_TYPE) values ('$user', '$pass','1','publisher')";
$sql['query2'] = "INSERT INTO t_label (LABEL) values('$user')";
$id_label = "select id_label from t_label where label ='".$user."'";
$id = $this->db->query($id_label)->result();
$sql['query3'] = "INSERT INTO t_publisher (PUBLISHER, ARTIS, ID_LABEL) values('$user', 'Various Artist', '$id')";
$result = array();
foreach($sql as $key => $value){

$result[$key] = $this->db->query($value);
}
```

please help :)

Answer (score 0):

`$id` is returning an object not a single value. Try inserting `$id->id_label` instead of just `$id`

Comment: where should i write $id->id_label?

Comment: in query3 where you're inserting $id as a value.

Comment: $sql['query3'] = "INSERT INTO t_publisher (PUBLISHER, ARTIS, ID_LABEL) values('$user', 'Various Artist', '$id->id_label')";
like that? i'd try.. but, its still 0 on the database :(

Comment: after the $id=$this->db->query($id_label)->result(); put print_r($id); die; What does it return?

Comment: after the alert showed, then white screen with Array ( ) written on it

Comment: it's returning empty then. Your query to get the id isn't working, sort that out and keep that print in there so you can see when it returns a value.

Comment: how should i do, then? what should i change?

Comment: You're going to have to troubleshoot the query. Make sure $user is actually giving you a value the same way I told you with $id. Just go through each query and make sure it's doing what it should. If one fails the way you have it they all fail. I don't know what your DB looks like or the values you're passing it, add to that I have to be up in 3 hours and there really isn't much more I can add, sorry.

Comment: ok, i'll try to search maybe there's wrong code. thanks then :)

Answer (score 0):

to get the id_label
try this

```
$id_result = $this->db->query($id_label);
foreach($id_result->result_array() as $row){
     $id=$row['id_label'];
}
```